# Redis client count with pipelines

Tags: go, redis, go-redis

I have just done an update to a GO application using pipeline, I noticed in my redis monitoring app that the number of clients connected just skyrocketed from 1/2 to 300+

I can't seem to find information on if this is normal for pipelines, they are connecting as a new client OR if this is unusual behaviour.

Has anyone else seen this ?

- Redis connection is a global.
- Redis setup is default.
- used in some go routines.

Example usage..

```
pipe := rdb.Pipeline()
pipe.set(ctx, "hi", "hi")
_, err := pipe.Execute()
```

What tends to happen is everytime pipeline is ran like the above it will create a new client - even though the pipeline is using the global redis connection.

Only happens with pipeline, other redis calls are fine.

Comment: This question needs more information, such as configuration or code, otherwise there is no way to judge and answer.

Comment: added some more information.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/go-redis/redis?

Comment: @caveman i am yes